# Bash modify value in file with user input

Tags: bash

I have a `config.py` file containing

```
config['port'] = 11111
```

I want to edit this file. The tricky part is I want `bash` to take input from me and replace 11111 with the input i give.

Comment: Is that the only line in your config.py file?  What do you mean by take input?  Do you want it to prompt for input or would you like to enter your input as a parameter?  What have you tried so far to accomplish this?

Comment: I want To Take Input Using read `'Port' avar`

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: I suggest that you instead modify the Python script to read the desired port from another standalone file.  The idea of a bash script written just to interactively modify a Python script makes me cringe.  It would make you cringe, too, if you had to maintain it.

Comment: Also see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Comment: while you're reading, don't forget our [welcome tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# script.sh

# Prompt the user for input
echo "Choose a port number: "

# Read the input to a variable
read PORT

# Update the configuration file
sed -i "s/^\(config\['port'\] =\)\s\+[0-9]\+$/\1 ${PORT}/" config.py
```

If this is your input file:

```py
# config.py
config['port'] = 123
```

And this is how you execute the command:

```
user@host:~$ bash script.sh
Choose a port number: 456
```

Then this is your updated file:

```py
# config.py
config['port'] = 456
```

Comment: You missed the part where igal explained how to run it ("your command") - by passing 456 as a parameter.

Comment: @AyushMishra Updated to prompt the user for input.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_port=12345
awk -v port="$new_port" '$0=="config['\'port\''] = 11111" { sub("11111",port); };
    { print; }' /path/to/file
```